# For aninhado só funciona na primeira iteração (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, csv

Estou tentando fazer com que um for aninhado compare linhas em dois arquivos csv diferentes, porém após a primeira interação do primeiro arquivo ser buscado dentro do segundo arquivo e pular para segunda iteração, o for2 deixa de ser executado e somente o for1 continua. Alguém saberia explicar o por quê?

```
def evolution(token, evolution_results):
    files_name = open("file_name_results/" + token + "_match_file.csv")
    results = open("results/" + token + "_results.csv")

    for line1 in files_name:
        print("Inicio iteração")
        line1 = line1.replace("\n","")
        if line1=="file" or line1=="":
            print("Fim iteração")
            continue
        print("Buscando "+line1)
        for line2 in results:
            line2 = line2.replace("\n","")
            if re.search('(=?' + ''.join(line1).strip() + ')', line2, re.IGNORECASE):
                # evolution_results.write(line2+"\n")
                print(line2)
        print("Fim iteração")
    print("Saiu do for")            
    files_name.close()
    results.close()
```

**obs:** no arquivo do for1 serão puladas sempre as duas primeiras linhas

## Saída

> Inicio iteração   Fim iteração   Inicio iteração   Fim iteração
> Inicio iteração   Buscando
> github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol
> c527907d648afdee3aa4f9ad2d6c44c5fdb2130a,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 317c0702eefe3909cbbaa53094340292a39c0ad4,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> b3935bb97eea724fd536ce87deaff53629e5aa25,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 3ffe6c9edb11b506817587ca5ab8b9913abd87d0,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 34d71ebe3777a2d9e0650b2e1f462def0e0096f0,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 12dd35e3d80115e23893a4ad07b0d6edc9f25403,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 85de77f365bc4fb8b269c45e983cc3a2cc5823d3,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,99
> 1cfb8d0957462a7f7fe289471b9e7863d32e2aab,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,100
> b1137aaa2536973339e8e4cd07d1129eefc0879c,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,100
> 7d2956a7a2b4209a0620ed0be1aa8be16f210cb6,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,100
> ce4b8dac9a0b5a76c5f09bd94ffe6f86f8dc9c62,github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SafeMath.sol,100
> Fim iteração   Inicio iteração   Buscando
> github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/IERC20Token.sol   Fim iteração
> Inicio iteração   Buscando
> github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/IOwned.sol   Fim iteração
> Inicio iteração   Buscando
> github_repos/bancor/solidity/contracts/SmartToken.sol   Fim iteração
> Saiu do for

Comment: Sabe o que são geradores em Python?

Comment: Não, sou novo com a linguagem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `open` retorna um [objeto de arquivo](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object). Ao lermos o conteúdo desse objeto, ou iterarmos sobre ele linha a linha como você faz no seu código, chegaremos ao "final" do arquivo. Nesse ponto, qualquer outra operação retornará um string vazio:

```
>>> arquivo = open('texto.txt')
>>> arquivo.read()
'olá mundo'
>>> arquivo.read()  # já cheguei ao final do arquivo
''
```

No seu caso, o problema é que o loop `for line2 in results:` percorre todo o arquivo aberto `results` na primeira vez que executa, e nas execuções seguintes esse loop não é executado (um loop sobre uma sequência vazia retorna imediatamente em Python, como por exemplo `for caractere in '': print(caractere)`).

Você tem algumas opções para contornar este problema:

#### 1) Guardar o conteúdo dos arquivos abertos em listas

Substituindo as primeiras linhas por:

```
files_name = open("file_name_results/" + token + "_match_file.csv").readlines()
results = open("results/" + token + "_results.csv").readlines()
```

Você lerá os arquivos inteiros em listas de strings, as quais podem ser iteradas quantas vezes você quiser. O resto do seu código deverá funcionar da forma como está.

#### 2) Chamar o método `seek` do arquivo aberto

Você pode usar o método [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) de um objeto de arquivo para voltar ao topo dele:

```
>>> arquivo = open('texto.txt')
>>> arquivo.read()
'olá mundo'
>>> arquivo.read()  # já cheguei ao final do arquivo
''
>>> arquivo.seek(0)  # voltando ao começo do arquivo
0
>>> arquivo.read()
'olá mundo'
```

Dessa forma, você pode chamar o método `results.seek(0)` no final do seu for loop aninhado para "restaurar" a condição inicial do arquivo aberto.

Comment: Muito obrigado :) gostei muito da sua explicação e ajudou a resolver o meu problema